# Can firebug open a local CSS file?

Tags: firefox, debug, firebug

With firePHP and fireLogger, i can click on the file name of the file that caused an error and open it with a text editor. I saw the option to configure editors with firebug - so my question is this:

Can Firebug be configured to open a local CSS sheet with an external editor when you click on the stylesheet in firebug?

[image]